# CarouselPage Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I have a CarouselPage and a ContentPage I would like to add the content page to the CarouselPage programmatically but when I do this nothing happens in the app.

I can see the items being added to the list but the pages are not shown when I run code below.

Any help on what I am doing wrong is much appreciated :)

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="DemoApp2.MainPage"
/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DemoApp2
{
    public partial class MainPage : CarouselPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<ContentPage> pages = new ObservableCollection<ContentPage>();

            pages.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 1"));
            pages.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 2"));
            pages.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 3"));
            pages.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 4"));
            pages.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 5"));

            this.ItemsSource = pages;

        }

    }
}
```

StoryPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="DemoApp2.StoryPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="YourLableName"
                   Text="Not Set"
                   TextColor="Black"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

StoryPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace DemoApp2
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class StoryPage : ContentPage
    {


        public string PageText = "";

        public StoryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PageText = "";

        }


        public StoryPage(string pageTextIn)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            YourLableName.TextColor = Color.Black;
            YourLableName.Text = pageTextIn;

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnAppearing");
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnDisappearing");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page) have a clear example of doing this.  If you want to use an `ItemsSource`, you have to supply a `DataTemplate`.  Otherwise you modify the page's `Children`

```
Children.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 1"));
Children.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 2"));
Children.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 3"));
Children.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 4"));
Children.Add(new StoryPage("This is page 5"));
```

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: @fox909a Hi, if answer be helpful and solved this, remember to mark that. Then other people who meet the same question will know the solution.